# In powershell, how can I get the exact original command used to invoke a function?

Tags: powershell

Is there something in `$MyInvocation` that does this? Or some way to extract it? I want the original text used for the arguments in the function call.

Comment: Are you looking for `$MyInvocation.Line`?

Comment: `$MyInvocation | fl *` will help you decide what you need : )

Answer (score 0):

There are some caveats to using `$myinvocation.line` or `$myinvocation.position`. If you split the invocation to your command across multiple lines (using backtick) then `.position` and `.line` won't show you the full command. It is safer to use splatting, `$args`/`$myinvocation.unboundarguments` (and don't define any parameters to your function) or $input (if your function gets pipeline input), depending on what you want to do with the command line. If you need to preserve spaces, though, using `.line` or `.position` are your only options.

Comment: Another problem with unbound arguments is that it still parses commas and in the case of unbound, removes them.

Answer (score -1):

`C:\script.ps1` :

```
function Say-MyName {
    $MyInvocation | fl *
}

Say-MyName
```

Pick your weapon :

```
MyCommand             : Say-MyName
BoundParameters       : {}
UnboundArguments      : {}
ScriptLineNumber      : 5
OffsetInLine          : 1
HistoryId             : 6
ScriptName            : C:\script.ps1
Line                  : Say-MyName
PositionMessage       : At C:\script.ps1:5 char:1
                        + Say-MyName
                        + ~~~~~~~~~~
PSScriptRoot          : C:\
PSCommandPath         : C:\script.ps1
InvocationName        : Say-MyName
PipelineLength        : 1
PipelinePosition      : 1
ExpectingInput        : False
CommandOrigin         : Internal
DisplayScriptPosition :
```