# How do I get the original expression used to invoke a powershell function?

Tags: function, powershell, reflection

How would I go about retrieving the *original* expression used to invoke a Powershell function, from within the function itself? As in, the expression as it was typed/read from the script or command line.

I know that one can use `$MyInvocation.Line` to retrieve the first *line* of the invocation expression, however this won't correctly retrieve a multi-line expression.

( [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34043733/2438926) only retrieves the first line, *or* the arguments, not the original expression)

Comment: Steven's answer is the perfect workaround, but as an aside re `$MyInvocation.Line` As of PowerShell 7.2, the only way to ensure that you see the _full_ command line that your function invocation was a part of (note that, given that multiple, `;`-separated statements can be placed on a single line, *other* statements may both precede and succeed your function call) is to place the entire call on a _single_ line. Since this limitation doesn't make sense, the behavior is arguably a _bug_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really meant for the debugger, but I think you can use `Get-PSCallStack` for this:

```
Function Get-Something {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$Param1
    )

    (Get-PSCallStack)[1].Position.Text
}

Get-Something `
1
```

Multiple lines to call it. The function should return the exact line that was called.

Note: Inside the function I had to reference the second element returned from `Get-PSCallStack` this is because `[0]` would be the `GetPSCallStack` command itself.  So, be forewarned, I can see this being finicky if it were nested down a bit.

[Get-PSCallStack Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-pscallstack?view=powershell-7.1#:%7E:text=Displays%20the%20current%20call%20stack.%20The%20Get-PSCallStack%20cmdlet,while%20in%20the%20debugger%2C%20type%20k%20or%20Get-PSCallStack.)

Comment: That's a great workaround, because not only does it capture the full invocation, irrespective of how many lines it spans, it also excludes _other_ statements that may have been part of the same submission, which `$MyInvocation.Line` _does_ report (on the first line only; e.g, submitting `Get-Date; Get-Something 1` makes `$MyInvocation.Line` inside `Get-Something` see that line verbatim, including the `Get-Date` call.)

Comment: Something I found out after trying this is that, while `.Position.Text` excludes most other statements, it does *not* exclude commands that are part of the invocation's pipeline.

Comment: I think that's what @mklement0 was saying.  However, I'd love to see a practical example.

Comment: Good point, @ClaySweetser. Steven, invoking `Get-Something 1 | Write-Output` echoes that very same text back, i.e. the _whole pipeline_, not just the segment that calls `Get-Something`